# how to Use fetch="join" in hbm file?

Tags: hibernate, fetching-strategy

in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820935/n1-query-not-working), i want to get the collection retrieved with a single select query by using `fetch="join"`. i made the following change on user.hbm file.

```
  <set name="phones"  table="PHONE_NUMBERS" cascade="all"  

lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <key column="UNID"/>
        <one-to-many class="PhoneNumber"/>
    </set>
```

but it still fires multiple queries . i also tried adding `fetch="join"` on both hbms, but it didnt work out. whats going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In general you are right - as stated in documentation:

#### [5.1.7. Mapping one to one and one to many associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3678)

*Small cite:*

> ... You can however adjust the fetching strategy, ie how data is fetched by using @Fetch. FetchMode can be SELECT (a select is triggered when the association needs to be loaded) or JOIN (use a SQL JOIN to load the association while loading the owner entity). **JOIN overrides any lazy attribute** (an association loaded through a JOIN strategy cannot be lazy)...

BUT, the [referenced question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820935/n1-query-not-working) is getting your root entity **USER** like this:

```
String hql = "from User ";
Query q = ses.createQuery(hql);
```

Which means, you are querying `User`. In this case the mapping `fetch="join"` is not evaluated.

We can do that by explicit JOIN

#### [16.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins)

an example from doc:

```
from Cat as cat
    join cat.mate as mate
    left join cat.kittens as kitten
```

So in our case:

```
String hql = "from User as u join u.phones as p ";
Query q = ses.createQuery(hql);
```

Finally - the mapped setting `fetch="join"` will be used whenever we are calling **`.get()`**

```
User user = session.get(id);
```